# color for download and upload

Tags: buttons, color-scheme, conventions, download, upload

Besides the down or up arrow, is there a convention of colors to distinguish between download and upload.

I have two buttons like these

[image]

and these too

[image]

But I feel that there's not enough visual difference for the actions. I thought of blue or red for download but I'm not 100% sure those are correct.

Comment: Is there a reason why you believe that a colour difference is more distinct compared to the direction of the arrows? I do believe that using the same colour makes the distinction less obvious, but at least there is also the connection people have with the direction of the arrow to the words (which does not apply with import and export). In general you want to apply a combination of strategies including text, colour, icon and other visual elements that form part of your design system.

Comment: @MichaelLai I don't have any particular reason, I just felt that a color difference must be present

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the tray to better visually aid the differentiation. 
As for color I could not see a defined norm but I saw green predominating downloads and blue for uploads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no common standards I've ever seen or read about assigning specific colours to up/download, and when trying to come up with a standard, it would have to depend on the context of the buttons. Even if you went with red=bad and green=good, an uploading application would want to assign the colours to a different direction to a downloading application.

A piece of software I have to use regularly has done this, using red and green buttons to choose between wiping the settings on the device and replacing them with your computer's settings, or wiping the settings on your computer and replacing them with those on the device. Which is which?

[image]

What you can do is look at the shape and layout rather than just the colours to differentiate the buttons.

At the moment the only difference between the actions is the bottom 12x12 pixels on a 50x25 pixel button, which is probably why you're looking into how to make the buttons look different. By rearranging the elements, you can make the buttons look much different from each other, and this could be combined with colour to make a bigger difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I think showing two icons for single feature is little confusing. So
>   you can try this options if you have enough space,

[image] [image]

[image]
[image]

> If not then this will also beautifully distinguish options

[image] [image]

**I've used font awesome upload download icons.**